# Please explain meaning/details of 'Properties are used for data binding; fields aren't.'

Tags: c#, properties

In this [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) article, I found the following:

Properties are used for data binding; fields aren't.

I would like to know meaning of it. Can someone please elaborate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you data bind a control, only the properties defined on the class you are binding can be used.

So, if your class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string aField = "something";

  public string aProperty { get; set;}

}
```

If you use data binding, you can use `aProperty` as a bound value, but not `aField`.

Read this overview of [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) on MSDN for more infomation.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very informative to me. However, I would like to know whether this kind of data binding (notify control or reflect change in control when value changes) is applicable to WPF only? The article I referred to would be written before WPF released, I guess, and then would the statement in my question have other meaning as well?

Comment: @CSharpLearner - It applies to all properties, not only WPF, but winforms too.

Answer (score 2):

Data binding requires that properties are able to *notify* the UI when they change. Fields can't do that by design. Properties, on the other hand, can do change notifications via suitable interfaces (e.g., `INotifyPropertyChanged`).